# Is there a way to see if a limit offset query has reached the end with pgpromse?

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

I have a table of posts. I would like to query these posts as pages. Because I would like to keep my endpoints stateless I would like to do this with offset and limit like this:

```
SELECT * FROM post LIMIT 50 OFFSET $1 ORDER BY id
```

Where $1 one would be the page number times the page size (50). The easy way to check if we have reached the end would be to see if we got 50 pages back. The problem of course is if the number of pages is divisible by 50, we can't be sure.
The way I have solved this until now is by simply fetching 51 posts per query with the page size still being 50. That way if the return query is less than 51, we have reached the end.

Unfortunately, this seems a very hacky way to do this. So I was wondering, is there some feature within pg-promise or postgresql that would indicate that I have reached the end of a table without resorting to tricks like this?

Comment: Short version - NO, there is no such "feature" in Postgres, you have to re-request data again to see if there is any left. And, `pg-promise` is not relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is no built in process for this directly. But you can count the rows and add that to the results. You could then even give the user the number of items or number of pages:

```
-- Item count
with pc(cnt) as (select  count(*)  from post)   
select p.*, cnt 
  from post p 
  cross join pc
 limit 50 offset $1; 

 -- page count
with pc(cnt) as (select  count(*)/50 + ((count(*)%50)>0)::int  from post)   
select p.*, cnt 
  from post p 
  cross join pc
 limit 50 offset $1;
```

Caution: The count function can be slow, and even when not it does add to response time. Is it worth the additional overhead? Only you and the user can answer that.

Comment: Instead of a CTE and a cross join, a subquery probably is simpler.

Comment: Perhaps, I look at it as more as stylistic choice. But I would probably test both.

Comment: I think ill stick with my solution, since i doesnt need to count all rows on each iteration and accomplishes basically the same use. thanks anyway

Answer (score 7):

The simplest method with the lowest overhead I found:

You can request `pageLimit+1` rows on every page request. In your controller you will check if `rowsCount > pageLimit` and will know that there is more data available. Of course, before returning the rows, you would need to remove the last element and send along the rows something like a `hasNext` boolean.

It is usually way cheaper for the DB to retrieve an extra row of data than count all rows or make an extra request for `page+1` to check if it returns any rows.

Comment: yep thats how I did it

Answer (score 0):

This method works well only in specific settings (SPA with caching of network requests and desire to make pagination feel faster with pre-fetching):

One every page, you make two requests: one for the current page data and one for the next page's data.

It works if you for example use a React Single-Page Application with `react-query` where the `nextPage` will not be refetched but reused when user opens it.

Otherwise, if the `nextPage` is not reused, it's worse than checking for a total number of rows to determine whether there are any rows left as you will make 2 requests for every page.

It will even make the user interface snappier as the transition to the next page will always be instant.

This method will work well if you have a lot of page transitions as the total number of calls equals numberOfPages+1, so if on average users go to 10 pages, numberOfPages+1=10+1 or just 10% overhead. But if your users usually do not go beyond the first page, it makes little sense as in this case numberOfPages+1=2 calls for a single page.